# Should TrySilentDownloadAndInstallStorePackageUpdatesAsync relaunch the app?

Tags: windows-store-apps, desktop, msix, microsoft-store

I'm testing with a win32 desktop app packaged as MSIX and released through the Microsoft Store. I'm trying to use TrySilentDownloadAndInstallStorePackageUpdatesAsync to update the app, which does seem to work, but quits immediately after the update is installed and doesn't relaunch the app.

The MS documentation seems to suggest that this function would relaunch the app (as suggested by the aptly named function IsNowAGoodTimeToRestartApp):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/self-install-package-updates

However, that's not what I observe. None of the debug statements following the call seem to hit, so it does seem like it is indeed terminating the app; it's just not relaunching it.

Looking for alternatives, there seems to be an old win32 API named RegisterApplicationRestart:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-registerapplicationrestart

But it has this caveat:
"To prevent cyclical restarts, the system will only restart the application if it has been running for a minimum of 60 seconds."

Which is less than ideal; what we're trying to accomplish is doing a quick check for updates, installing them and relaunching, so on the next run there should be no updates to apply and no further need to restart. Waiting 60 seconds here defeats the purpose of a quick check.

What are the alternatives? Any way to get the app to relaunch after installing a MS Store update?

(As a side note: is there any way to test MS store updates without going through the certification process? It can take hours, which completely kills the write-build-test cycle).

Comment: *"is there any way to test MS store updates without going through the certification process?"* - I believe there is (was?), but I'm unable to dig up the documentation. I'll ask Cortana (who is having a bad day today, and insists on being called "Bing"...).

Comment: Now I remember, the documentation for [`StoreContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storecontext) gave the hint: The [`CurrentAppSimulator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentAppSimulator) used to be the closest thing to local testing we had. It was introduced when Microsoft were still confident that the UWP is the future, and the UWP is the only application model supported. Unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

`IsNowAGoodTimeToRestartApp` method is just a place holder which represents the logic you need to do to check if the app is ready to install updates.

[StoreContext.TrySilentDownloadAndInstallStorePackageUpdatesAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storecontext.trysilentdownloadandinstallstorepackageupdatesasync?view=winrt-22621) will not relaunch the app.

Comment: How can I call CoreApplication.RequestRestartAsync(String) if StoreContext.TrySilentDownloadStorePackageUpdatesAsync kills the app? As I said, the debug statements I posted after the return from TrySilentDownloadStorePackageUpdatesAsync never show, indicating the app gets terminated by calling it.

Comment: @LeonardoMesquita I misunderstand your description that you are asking for `TrySilentDownloadStorePackageUpdatesAsync`. **TrySilentDownloadAndInstallStorePackageUpdatesAsync** will not launch your app. The switch statements in the sample code are prepared for the case of download failure and installation failure

Comment: Fair enough. But then, how do I relaunch the app after installation?

Comment: Just talk from the UWP or WinRT API side, there is no way to do that.